# Putty server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: putty

I'm getting this error when using Putty:

> Server unexpectedly closed network connection

I think there is a problem with the network in my office because all computers at my work workplace have the same problem. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If this error happens after a while that you are connected to the host, probably in your work network have some router periodically closing the connections, a workaround for this is keep your terminal busy, running something like top when you are away, but remember this creates a security breach.

Basically your connection is being closed by inactivity, if you just keep something running in your terminal, is more likely that it doesn't close the connection, I mean by something running as the terminal screen being refreshed constantly, if you run a Linux box, type the command `top`, that shows the box load and refreshes every 5 seconds.

Comment: That's is exactly what happens- I mean "after a while that you are connected to the host". Can you explain me the solution more clearly? - unfortunately I am not the web administrator so i need more dummy explaination. I would be appreciate.

Comment: Your connection is being closed by inactivity, if you just keep something running in your terminal, is more likely that it doesn´t close the connection, I mean by something running as the terminal screen being refreshed constantly, if you run a linux box, type the command top, that shows the box load and refreshes every 5 seconds.

Comment: I am using WinSCP client under windows 7. Please give me some clues what and where exactly should i do under this operation system.
Thank's.